# My image look changes when i modify the render resolution

Tags: rendering, light, resolution

If i render my scene in 1280x720 it looks ok but whe i increase the resolution to 2560x1440 the ground looks darker . I only changed the resolution,nothing more:

The first image was a test and the second a final render . I want the final render to look like the first image.What i should do ?
(THE UNFINISHED RENDER HAS 2560X1440 AND THE OTHER ONE 1280X720)

[image]
[image](

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you haven't changed any setting, like the color management or ray visibility options? Then please share the .blend file, because resolution changes shouldn't have that kind of effect on the shadows.

Comment: Hello :). So, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the resizing process, when the software used to display the rendering tries to fit the image onto the size of your monitor.